# How to configure Webhooks for QuickBooks by using API?

Tags: webhooks, quickbooks-online

I have been working on QuickBooks Webhooks integration. According to QB's document, If I want to configure Webhooks, I have to log in to my account, go to Setting tab then and click Add Webhooks button. So, Can I do it manually? I mean that are there any APIs to do this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I mean that are there any APIs to do this?

No.

You have to do it manually.